# Statistics on Mexican illicit drug exports by country?

Tags: international-trade, statistics, black-market

Estimates of the size of the total Mexican illicit drug export markets are somewhere around USD 200-650 billion per annum, depending on the source:

- [\$426-652 billion per year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_drug_trade)
- [\$500 billion](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2019/06/24/do-mexican-drug-cartels-make-billion-year/)
- [\$200-300 billion](https://www.unodc.org/pdf/WDR_2005/volume_1_chap2.pdf)

Are there any available statistics (estimates) on the breakdown **by destination country**?

Note that if an export goes through one or more intermediary countries, they don't matter, it's the destination (i.e. country in which the goods are finally sold/consumed) that matters.

I found a simple graph [here](https://www.statista.com/statistics/478682/mexican-pharmaceutical-exports-by-country/) showing precisely this information, but for *legal*/pharmaceutical drugs. Is there something similar for Mexico's illicit drug export market?

Comment: I feel that the information you seek would require a considerable amount of transparency by the exporters. You'd thus require drug barons and drug traffickers to be transparent on their activities in a similar manner to Johnson & Johnson.

Comment: @EB3112 there are a bunch of ways to estimate them though. Seizures is one, interviews with major cartels is another (some do actually give interviews for research purposes from time to time), information volunteered from arrests etc. It may not be as accurate as, say, the annual report by a publicly listed company, but that’s a given since illicit drug exporters don’t formally report their exports.

Comment: That's anecdotal evidence prone to large discrepancy however, no? Some way wish   significantly underestimating activities to hide loot, or perhaps even overestimate to emphasise their status. I dunno. Good luck on your search with that one

Comment: @EB3112 Publicly listed companies (who report earnings publicly) are also subject to regularly vague accounting rules, and also have incentives to manipulate figures to their advantage. You're right in your observation that any figures might not be perfectly accurate, and probably more inaccurate than those of publicly listed companies, but that doesn't mean it's not worth estimating. To many policy makers, these figures could be more important than those of a NASDAQ listed company, even taking into consideration their likely higher margin of error.